# How to make an ASP.NET MVC Controller GET method get invoked only from a link?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this `Confirm` method in my `Account` controller to which I redirect the users to when they click the `link` I've sent them to their email to activate their account. The returned view displays a message whether the activation has succeeded or not.

The problem is that if the user types in the url `.../account/confirm/...` they would also be able to see this view (this view should be available only for people who have received an email with the link).

Is there any way to specify that this method must be called only from a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "called from a link". Someone typing in the URL, copy-pasting the URL from the mail or directly clicking the link in the mail all end up exactly the same in your controller.

The only difference would be a link clicked from an HTTP (not HTTPS) page, where sometimes the referrer is set. You shouldn't rely on that though, as it is user-supplied and can thus be modified by the user. Certain browser settings or plugins disable the referrer altogether.

Add a token to the URL and check that. If it's not present or invalid, display a 404 or whatever you want.